# Concurrent task in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Currently I am running 3 task concurrently using AFNetworking.But my problem is that I need to refresh tableview once all the above three task complete.But as in AFNetworking all the operation are async. So any operation can finish first. I am not getting a point where I need to refresh my tableview. I am planning to do some critical section type implementation.Is there can other way to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in [batched request operation feature of AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/batchOfRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:). The completion handler for the batch would include the logic to refresh your data source once all of the operations have finished.

Comment: Actually, that might be a better solutions than my answer! +1

Comment: Thanks.I missed this from AFNetworking documentation. I will try.

Comment: @iPhoneDev I didn't know about the existents of this either. Using this build in functionality is probably a cleaner solution although my solution will work just as well. Use what works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe having some sort of **'active requests array'** is a solution for you.

- Every time you make a request, add it to the (mutable) array.
- When the request finishes, remove it from the array.
- Every time a request finishes, check the array length (count).
- If your array has become empty again, all request have been finished and you can reload your tableview.

Comment: Good idea, +1 for you guy

Comment: Hi Maarten, so according to you. I have an array. For example I add a task in array at index 0.On the task completion method I will remove the task from index 0 and check the array length.Am I correct.

Comment: Exactly. But don't just set it to an index. Create a mutable array, add the request object with addObject: and then just use the success and failure blocks of your request to remove it from the 'active requests array'.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help. If this answer solved your problem, I would appreciate it when you upvote and accept it.

Comment: sure buddy. I am going to implement.Once I will complete I will do upvote.

Comment: Great! Good luck with the implementation